# Django ORM better way to manipulate django ORM query to find related data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**Models:**

```
class Tweets(models.Model):

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=now, verbose_name="Created on")
    tweet_data = models.TextField(verbose_name='tweet message')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=DO_NOTHING)

class UserFollowers(models.Model):

    follower_user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name="follower")
    followee_user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name="followee")
```

**The UserFollowers table has record for who follows whom.**

Here,
I need to get all tweets posted by people I follow

Current approach:

```
        myfollowees = UserFollowers.objects.filter(follower_user=user_idx)
        print(myfollowees)
        myfolloweeslist = []
        for ele in myfollowees:
            myfolloweeslist.append(ele.followee_user.id)
        my_timeline_tweets = Tweets.objects.filter(user_id__in = myfolloweeslist)
```

1. generate the my followee list (list of people I follow)
2. fetch tweets where tweet is posted by **userid** and is also present in myfolloweelist

I would like to know if there is a better way to handle this.

I tried this and it worked for just one value of user_idx but not for others:

```
        my_timeline_tweets = Tweets.objects.filter(user__follower = user_idx)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Tweet.objects.filter(user__followee__follower_user=user_idx)
```

This will retrieve the `Tweet`s for which the `.user` is a `User` object for which a `UserFollowers` object exists with the `.user` of the `Tweet` as `followee_user`, and as `follower_user` the `user_idx`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Is there any resource to read about how to write the relationships about ORM filtering.

Comment: @akashdeep: perhaps you can follow the [*making queries*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/) section of the documentation. This is explains quite well how to make more advanced queries. It might also help to write these queries in the shell and thus *experiment* with the discussed techniques.